# When should I use *ngIf over hidden property and vice versa?

Tags: angular

I'm aware of the difference between `*ngIf` and `hidden` property in Angular:

> **`*ngIf`**: Adds/Removes the element to DOM.
>
> **`hidden`**: Simply shows/hides the element in DOM.

What I'm not sure is the proper condition(?) to choose one over the other. Removing an element at one condition and adding it again sounds a bit expensive but at the same time, it doesn't seem right to let it stay in DOM with `hidden` property.

I've been sticked to `*ngIf` as much as I can but it sometimes emits an error when I try accessing the element in the `*ngIf` template even after I change the condition of `*ngIf` to `true` (probably because I'm not used to the cycle of the DOM update). In these case, I use `hidden` property, not because it seems right.

So the point is, I'd like to know the clear standard/criterion to choose one over the other.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found some better answer in Angular document for your question. Hope it will provide you with clear approach to find out better selection from `*ngIf` and `hidden`.

<kbd>[From Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#why-remove-rather-than-hide)</kbd>

> The difference between hiding and removing doesn't matter for a simple
>   paragraph. It does matter when the host element is attached to a
>   resource intensive component. Such a component's behavior continues
>   even when hidden. The component stays attached to its DOM element. It
>   keeps listening to events. Angular keeps checking for changes that
>   could affect data bindings. Whatever the component was doing, it keeps
>   doing.
>
> Although invisible, the component—and all of its descendant
>   components—tie up resources. The performance and memory burden can be
>   substantial, responsiveness can degrade, and the user sees nothing.
>
> On the positive side, showing the element again is quick. The
>   component's previous state is preserved and ready to display. The
>   component doesn't re-initialize—an operation that could be expensive.
>   So hiding and showing is sometimes the right thing to do.
>
> But in the absence of a compelling reason to keep them around, your
>   preference should be to remove DOM elements that the user can't see
>   and recover the unused resources with a structural directive like [`NgIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)
>   .
>
> These same considerations apply to every structural directive, whether
>   built-in or custom. Before applying a structural directive, you might
>   want to pause for a moment to consider the consequences of adding and
>   removing elements and of creating and destroying components.

Comment: Wow I hadn't thought of it this way! It helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @DongBin Kim glad to help you! happy coding :)

Comment: sidenote: if you use **ngIf* the page can flicker due to removing the element from DOM whereas *[hidden]* will not affect the design and position of elements of DOM.

Comment: @coder Apart from the resource/memory point of view, what about the issue I described in my writing? Maybe because of the DOM creation timing issue, I sometimes can't access the element via template variable with the error `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`. In these cases, I always had to choose `hidden` property.

Comment: @DongBin Kim yes your thought is correct. as soon as we change the `*ngIf` to `true` and then we are try access the element at the same time we could have such glitches. have to wait until they are ready to use

Comment: @coder Then, we have no options other than sticked to `hidden` property in this case?

Comment: @DongBin Kim there is another option to use really little bit of a timeout before access those element. but could be cause some performance issue because of timeout.

Answer (score 4):

There have been two occasions in which I have had reasons to choose one over the other:

- Choose `*ngIf` when using `[hidden]` will cause a performance problem (hundreds of hidden tags are still in the DOM and can cause sluggish rendering of your website).
- Choose `[hidden]` when you still need to initialize the hidden component, and pass events to it, even if you are not going to show it.

Besides these 2 rules, it's a matter of what feels right to your setup.

I give you an example of each one I had found in real life:

### Choose `*ngIf` when using `[hidden]` will cause a performance problem

Imagine you have a `Ticket` object and you keep track of modification to each ticket by using a list of `Log` objects. Each log represents a type of change that needs to be rendered differently (for example: closing a ticket generates a log that shows the old and new state, but adding a file to a ticket shows a preview of the file).

One possible implementation is using `[hidden]` like this:

```
<span [hidden]="logType !== 1">...</span>
<span [hidden]="logType !== 2">...</span>
<span [hidden]="logType !== 3">...</span>
...
<span [hidden]="logType !== 30">...</span>
```

Then for every log in your page you'll have 29 hidden DOM elements. Now, if your ticket gets modified a lot, say 10 modifications you'll end up with 290 hidden elements in your DOM, which will be using memory and are slower to render.

In that case, changing the `[hidden]` to `*ngIf` removes completely the 290 extra objects.

### Choose `[hidden]` when you still need to initialize the hidden component

Check this other situation:

**Ticket.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="numLogs > 0">
    <h1>Logs</h1>
    <ticket-logs [ticketId]="ticket.id"
                 (onNumLogsRetrieved)="setNumLogs($event)"></ticket-logs>
</ng-container>
```

Where `setNumLogs($event)` is the one that sets the value of `numLogs`.

Notice that with a `*ngIf` the `ticket-logs` component will never be instantiated, so `numLogs` will always be `0`. In this case you need to use a `[hidden]` which gives the `ticket-logs` component the opportunity to invoke `setNumLogs` to hide the `h1` and itself.

(Note in this case we can't have `ticket-logs` hide its own contents because we would still be showing the `h1` tag.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Let me ask you one thing to make something clear: Say, there's a code like `<ng-container *ngIf="show"><div #div></div></ng-container>`. At certain point, I want to access the `div` element so I try like: `this.show = true; // do Something with this.div.nativeElement` And the problem is that an error is emitted saying `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined.` Is this an expected behaviour? I'm asking this because in my knowledge, I should be able to access it because I set the `show` variable to `true`.

Comment: That can certainly give you trouble because of the `#div`: if you reference `#div` while *Angular thinks* `show = false` then `#div` won't exist. Notice that setting `this.show = true` doesn't immediately cause the `#div` to exist, you'll need to wait until Angular has digested the changes and updated the DOM, and then you will have access to `#div`. If you could provide the exact code (in a different question as this one is partly unrelated) then we could see how the code could be refactored for not needing to wait until Angular has updated the DOM.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318338/ngif-dom-update-timing-issue-in-angular I've posted a question about this matter. I'd appreciate your insight if you would take a look!

Answer (score 1):

**ngIf** is a directive provided by the Angular. It is used to add or remove the html content in angular applications. If we are providing false it will remove the content.

eg

```
<div *ngIf="isValid"> Data is valid. </div>
```

**hidden** can be user to just hide the content from page. It doesn't remove the DOM elements. But it just hide

eg

```
<div hidden> Data is valid. </div>
```

When should we use *ngIf?

It can be used when some fields in a form which should be removed for a particular user. Then you can use *ngIf. Because anyone can make the DOM element visible by removing the hidden from dom. So if a field should not be used by anyone in a particular condition it is better to user *ngIf

Answer (score 0):

*ngIf is used when you want the DOM element to be dynamically inserted based on a condition.
With the hidden attribute, you will always have the DOM element present and you can get it anytime from the DOM, but it won't be visible(obviously) to the user.

So, use *ngIf when you don't want the element to be present in the DOM at all.
Use hidden element when you want to have some data stored(for posting purpose perhaps, with the visible form elements) and need to access it for some reason, keeping it hidden for the user.

Comment: Sometimes, I wanted certain elements to be removed completely and dynamically inserted in DOM so I tried it with `*ngIf` but as I described in my writing, because of the cycle/timing issue, I couldn't access the element in the `*ngIf` directive with template variables even after changing the condition to `true` so I just chose `hidden` property instead.