# *ngIf DOM update timing issue in Angular

Tags: angular

```
<ng-container *ngIf="show">
  <div #tooltip>
    // some elements
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Say, there's a template like above. I'd like to set position of the tooltip each time a method is called:

```
export class AComponent {
 @ViewChild('tooltip') tooltip: ElementRef;
 show: boolean;

 constructor(
   private renderer: Renderer2
 )

 methodA(e: MouseEvent): void {
  this.show = true;
  const tooltip = this.tooltip.nativeElement;

  this.renderer.setStyle(tooltip, 'left', e.offsetX - tooltip.offsetWidth + 'px');
 }
```

But when I run this code, I get an error `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`, which I'm guessing DOM hasn't got updated since I reset the `show` property to `true` so `tooltip` property doesn't exist in DOM.

So I had to go with `hidden` property:

```
<div #tooltip [hidden]="show">
   // some elements
</div>
```

There's no problem with this way but I'm wondering if there's any other workaround to make it work with `*ngIf` approach. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just use binding ([style.left] or ngStyle) to set the style, instead of messing up with ViewChild and renderer?

Comment: you can put it in an if ```if(this.tooltip){
      console.log(this.tooltip)
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.tooltip.nativeElement,    'left', e.clientX + 'px');
  }```

Comment: @JBNizet It's because I need to set `left` with some calculation which requires the width of the element itself. I updated my question.

Comment: @fatemefazli It works with your suggestion because the method is called continuously but if the case was a "one-time" thing, wouldn't it be a problem because the method would not run the code at first when DOM hasn't got updated yet.

Comment: @DongBin Kim methodA is called only on MouseEvent right?

Comment: @nargh That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the style to the template and give it a dynamic value. The `calculateLeft` method will only be called when a valid `#tooltip` is in the DOM.

Also notice there is no need for the `ViewChild` nor `Renderer2` in this case:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AComponent {
    show: boolean;
    lastOffsetX: number;

    public methodA(e: MouseEvent): void {
        this.show = true;
        this.lastOffsetX = e.offsetX;
    }

    public calculateLeft(tooltip) {
        return (this.lastOffsetX - tooltip.offsetWidth) + 'px';
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="show">
    <div #tooltip [ngStyle]="{left: calculateLeft(tooltip)}">
        Hello
    </div>
</ng-container>
<button (click)="methodA($event)">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I've tried this approach but it gives me this error: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.` I'm guessing it's because the methodA is called continuously(in my app, it's called on `mouseover` event, not on `click` event)

Comment: That exception can happen if you change a parent's field from inside a child component. But I'd need to see the actual code snippet to point to where the issue comes from.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.ref.detectChanges() by importing  ChangeDetectorRef of angular to force the DOM to detect changes.
Here is the documentation for the same:
https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: It might work but I don't want to invoke the change detection manually because the method I'm implementing is called continuously and the change detection would be invoked too many times.

Comment: Sometimes, that's how we can detectChanges that are not otherwise picked up on it's own. You can put a condition to check if the element.length==0 and only then call this to avoid invoking it many times.